# How to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 for non-responsive site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can read on their page, the new [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile) is "mobile first":

> With Bootstrap 2, we added optional mobile friendly styles for key
>   aspects of the framework. **With Bootstrap 3, we've rewritten the
>   project to be mobile friendly from the start**. Instead of adding on
>   optional mobile styles, **they're baked right into the core**. In
>   fact, Bootstrap is mobile first. Mobile first styles can be found
>   throughout the entire library instead of in separate files.

How can I disable the responsiveness? I want that my site will not rearrange itself for tablet or mobile.

Comment: @devo: if you want to promote a question, it's better to put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For a more explained procedure see [How to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 for non-responsive site](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/11/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site/)

From [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) (plus some explanations):

> To disable responsive features, follow these steps. See it in action
>   in the modified template below.
>
> 1) **Remove (or just don't add) the viewport `<meta>`** mentioned in the CSS docs

self-explanatory

> 2) Remove the max-width on the **`.container`** for all grid tiers with
>   max-width: none !important; and set a regular width like width:
>   970px;. Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You
>   can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some
>   selector-fu.

Add this style:

```
.container{
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 970px;
}
```

> 3) If using **navbars**, undo all the navbar collapsing and expanding
>   behavior (this is too much to show here, so peep the example).

Open `variables.less` and set the variables:

`@grid-float-breakpoint` to `0`

`@screen-xs-max` to `0` (this will be fixed; read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18902276/1252920))

> 4) For grid layouts, **make use of .col-xs-* classes** in addition to or
>   in place of the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device
>   grid scales up to all resolutions, so you're set there.

self-explanatory

> You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are
>   still there and need to be picked up). This just disables the "mobile
>   site" of Bootstrap.

Comment: Removing viewport meta only disables responsiveness on mobile devices, but will have no effect on desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Without major mods to the source, it just doesn't seem possible.

The following link details the changes needed:
http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-twitters-bootstrap-3-without-responsive-features/

Answer (score 4):

The Bootstrap 3 docs actually contain a paragraph for this issue: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was looking for the same thing. I haven't checked it out yet, so I can't attest to it's functionality, but here is a version with responsive taken out:

https://github.com/bassjobsen/non-responsive-tb3

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here by Jay Douglass which details overriding the media query breakpoint variables to disable the responsive features. It's a simple solution that requires minimal change.

[How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-do-i-remove-the-responsive-functionality-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

With a small effort you can achieve that.

1) Remove viewport

2) Add `.container{ max-width: none !important; width: 970px; }` to your css file

3) If using navbars, undo all the navbar collapsing and expanding behavior

4)

> For grid layouts, make use of .col-xs-* classes in addition to or in
>   place of the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device
>   grid scales up to all resolutions, so you're set there.

You can follow the link below:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: 3) "If using navbars, undo all the navbar collapsing and expanding behavior" - Most elaborate help written about a topic, ever!

Comment: @Michael You are right, that's not how it should be. That sentence comes from bootstrap's site. Anyway, if you are using any Bootstrap's navbar component, you gotta remove all it's collapsing and expanding tags. To see the example follow the link. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/  I hope this helps