# Fixed size bootstrap navbar and image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="logo"></div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SOFTWARE &amp; WEB DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GAME DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ARTS &amp; DESIGNS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hi i need help with my bootstrap navbar, whenever I minimize or maximize my webpage, the navbar header i made keeps resizing. what code should i add and/or change in order to make the size consistent? P.S. my image wont resize as well, stuck in the same size and hides my carousel if the window size is small.

[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAgjp.jpg)

[Smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmqfC.png)

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738417/bootstrap-remove-responsive-from-navbar

Answer (score 0):

[Create whit layoutit](http://www.layoutit.com/build)

get element f12 or save whit login

Comment: im sorry what do you mean by that?