# How to set container width to 980px in bootstrap 3.0.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3.0 I can wrap `.container` class with my class and set the `width` to my class to `980px`

EX

```
             <div class="maincontainer">
                   <div class="container">
                       //some content
                   </div>
             </div>
```

CSS

```
         .maincontainer {
             max-width: 980px;
             margin:0 auto;
         }
```

That code will wrap my contents with `980px`, 
but in bootstrap 3.0.2 the author has change class `.container` to `width` not `max-width` in bootstrap 3.0.

So it is hard to set `980px` for my layout!!
I'm using LESS css!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

### A few of choices

In bootstrap, if one is using responsive design on the grid, then `width` is set by a variable ([currently in 3.0.2 on line 43 of grid.less and following, depending on size](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less#L43)).

**Choice #1**

Change [the `@container-XX` variable(s)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L628) controlling the width in the `variables.less` file to achieve the `980px` (for whatever size(s) you want it) which will then make the `.container` control the width and be what you want. I recommend this only if you actually still want some form of responsive site.

**Choice #2**

If you want to control the width still by your `.maincontainer` class, then in the same variable file noted in #1, change all the `@container-XX` (for `sm`, `md`, `lg`) to be `auto` which will make elements fit to the wrapping container `.maincontainer`.

**Choice #3**

If you do not want a responsive site at all, but a statically set `980px` then follow the directions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943264/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site).

**My guess is you actually want #3**, but I thought I would mention the other ideas as well.