# How to change bootstrap3 deafult container width changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

change bootstrap 3 default container width with out any alignment issue,

The default container width is

```
.container {
      width: 1170px;
}
```

I need to change

```
.container {
     width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set container width to 980px in bootstrap 3.0.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011462/how-to-set-container-width-to-980px-in-bootstrap-3-0-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[click and customize](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)Bootstrap site and choose the size you require. set @gridColumnWidth and @gridGutterWidth variables.

example:

```
 @gridColumnWidth = 50px and @gridGutterWidth = 100px results on a 1000px layout.
```

Then download it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want only for that page then you can write a css in that file like

```
<style>
.container {
        width: 960px !important;
  }
</style>
```

or you can add it to your main tempalte css the same way with important keyword