# Responsiveness with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable bootstrap's responsiveness on my main page for my website, but the instructions are completely alien to me. Could someone could just explain what they mean and what I have to do to the code.

The instructions for disabling Bootstrap's responsiveness are here:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to remove the following `meta tag from the head of your page:

   ```html
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   ```
2. In your css file add:

   ```css
   .container {
       width: 970px !important;
   }
   ```
3. Remove the collapse navbar classes from your navbar
4. In grid system just use the `.col-xs-` class

Comment: What do you mean by removing the collapse navbar classes from the navbar? Is there something I need to take out from that code?

Comment: There are some classes with the name collapse, like navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse, if you are using on of those you should remove them, if you don't use them, don't do nothing.
I hope my answer help you, I never used Bootstrap without Responsive design, I just read what the doc says and tell you , so I'm not 100% sure if it works or not

Comment: Found a line like this


<button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="icon-bar"></span>

What should I remove from there? I tried removing the .navbar-collapse and the datatoggle=collapse but that just broke it. There was another line that said this:


<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                      <a class="" href="/play"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> Info</a>
                    </li>


After this a couple more <li>,what to take away?

Comment: That's the button of the "mobile menu" . I think you'll need to remove it because it have the "collape" class...

Comment: You'll need to do your website without those classes... Found a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943264/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site.
If I helped you somehow please vote in my answer.
I'm not an expert so I can't help you so much, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap documentation itself explains you how to disable responsive features but it's not so clear.

Here is a post that explains that step by step:
http://coderpills.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site/