# ISO 8 ignores meta viewport and automatically makes site responsive in iphone 6

Tags: css, iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap, iso

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0">
```

this is my code which does not runs on iPhone 6 and my site automatically becomes responsive

what should i do,
site is built in bootstrap 3
and i have used `non-responsive.css`

Comment: Why you are creating non-responsive if are you doing in bootstrap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 for non-responsive site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943264/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site)

Comment: its our client requirement, first he said to make responsive after that he demands to remove responsiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this mate tag in your header for this situation add content width that your container have and see

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1120"/>
```

Comment: ah thanks my container width is 1170 and when i added it site runs on iphone6, let me check on other iphone too

Comment: Ok then you can add your content width 1170 in meta tag