# Can't disable responsiveness of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to ask how can I disable responsiveness of Bootstrap. I currently followed the instructions in the tutorial but I can't make my page non-responsive.

What I did in my code is:

```
1. I removed the viewport in meta tag
2. Set a width in the class .container
```

When I resized my windows the 3 columns are became responsive.

[Here's my sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/qugzo9u1)

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chuosenko</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./third_party/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./third_party/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./third_party/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./third_party/jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./third_party/jqueryui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./third_party/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./third_party/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/packery.pkgd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>COL 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>COL 2</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>COL 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my css:

```
.container {
  width: 1280px;
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: use `col-xs-*`class for grid (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943264/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site)

Comment: @muthan You should submit that as an answer so Jerielle can accept it. That will avoid this question hanging around as unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

use `col-xs-*` class for grid. Like suggested in the tutorials.