# Override responsiveness bootstrap 3 @media print

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am trying to prevent responsive features of bootstrap on the event `javascript:print()` such that my web page remains in the column grid arrangement I have determined regardless of pixels size.

I could as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978842/1376627) recompile the less with different breakpoints and serve a second css file on print.

But I don't want to have to serve a new css file.

I am trying to do something like this

```
@media print and (min-width: 480px) { 
  .col-xs-12 {
    float: none; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  .....
}
```

Comment: What responsive features are you looking to remove from the print version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I came up with, taken straight from bootstrap's highest resolution `@media` query

```
@media print {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: 0;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: 0;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```