# Why i can't disable responsive bootstrap in my project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big problem. I use bootstrap ver 3.1.1 in my website, and i want disable responsive of bootstrap in this project, but i can't!

This is html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: yellow;">col left</div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: pink;">col right</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my custom css:

```
body {
    background-color:#fdfdfd !important;
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma !important;
    min-width: 1024px !important;
}
.container {
    max-width: none !important;
    width:1024px !important;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

remove meta tag in header page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but when i test my web in firefox, chrome... element div 'container' is fixed size when i resize width of brower. But navbar-menu, gird system is responsive. Why? Please help me.

Sorry because my english is not good!

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable responsiveness of bootstrap by including [non-responsive.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css).

For more details on it see [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive).

Answer (score 2):

**Build you custom :**

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

*(Uncheck that Responsive utilities checkbox)*

---

Comment: I'm try it, but navbar is responsive when resize brower. I don't why :(

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Comment: Do you have any example about "If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior". I don't understand about this. Thanks @dotty!