# How can I work without the resize alteration?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’ve made a web page with Bootstrap and I don’t want it to be changed by changing the size of web browser
Generally speaking, what I intend is that my web page to be scrolled, not to be changed in size.

I have uploaded a picture too

[**Correct Image**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly2yn05mrb574zx/1.jpg)

[**not correct image**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nghqxvw7ig3q3s/2.JPG)

[**jsffidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/N2WZC/)

```
     <div class="row1 col-lg-12">
            <div class="speed">
                <p>128/128</p>
            </div>
            <div class="code-tarefe">
                <p>H 128 T3</p>
                <p>H 128 T6</p>
                <p>H 128 T10</p>

            </div>
            <div class="speed-dw-up">
                <p>از 16 تا 128 کیلوبایت</p><br/>
                <p>معادل</p><br/>
                <p>kb 128 تا 1024 کیلوبیت </p><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="hajme">
                <p>3G</p>
                <p>6G</p>
                <p>10G</p>
            </div>
            <div class="yekmahe">
                <p>15,000</p>
                <p>25,000</p>
                <p>45,000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="chaharmahe">
                <p>57,000</p>
                <p>95,000</p>
                <p>171,000</p>
            </div>

            <div class="hashtmahe">
                <p>108,000</p>
                <p>180,000</p>
                <p>324,000</p>
            </div>

            <div class="yeksale">
                <p>153,000</p>
                <p>255,000</p>
                <p>459,000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="hargig">
                <p>5,000</p>
                <p>4,200</p>
                <p>4,500</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of this code will fix the problem.

```
.grey_section { min-width: 1200px; }


.container {min-width: 1200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do ist  to remove or comment out responsive features ("MEDIA QUERIES") in Twitter Bootstrap

if you are using Bootstrap 3 [ckeck this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)