# Hosted Bootstrap 3.2 make Non Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I've tried afew things  so far to try and get this to work,

So far i've tried:

```
// Media queries breakpoints
// --------------------------------------------------

// Extra small screen / phone
// Note: Deprecated @screen-xs and @screen-phone as of v3.0.1
@screen-xs:                  1px;
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;

// Small screen / tablet
// Note: Deprecated @screen-sm and @screen-tablet as of v3.0.1
@screen-sm:                  2px;
@screen-sm-min:              @screen-sm;
@screen-tablet:              @screen-sm-min;

// Medium screen / desktop
// Note: Deprecated @screen-md and @screen-desktop as of v3.0.1
@screen-md:                  3px;
@screen-md-min:              @screen-md;
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md-min;

// Large screen / wide desktop
// Note: Deprecated @screen-lg and @screen-lg-desktop as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg:                  9999px;
@screen-lg-min:              @screen-lg;
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg-min;
```

Ive tried this [Twitter Bootstrap Disable Responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Changed container and body to `style="min-width: 1020px"` and `style="width: 1020px"`

I'm not sure if this is possible at all but I would like to use CDNJS to host the bootstrap files but make it non responsive as my design doesn't allow for this.

Any help or direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: @JordanD i've tried that and it doesn't work, i'm asking to amend a hosted Bootstrap on CDNJS, what i'm asking is completely different. That questioin is over a year old and its Version 3.2 now!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, CDNs don't generally intend on allowing developers to host modified versions of libraries.

You have a few options:

1. Use the same hosted version you've been using before, but override CSS with additional stylesheets in your application as needed.
2. Don't use a CDN. You could also serve your own, and there is software that makes this easier to manage.
3. Create a fork of Bootstrap with a different name and [fork cdnjs](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/fork) to add your fork. Note that this may be difficult to have accepted unless a significant number of other developers start using it.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas do you have any way to make it non responsive, i've tried all above but i just cant seem to get it to be non responsive, i'm sure theirs an easy code solution but ill keep looking. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to fix a specific issue in your modified code that makes something not as responsive as necessary, or how to host the responsive version or otherwise use it with an existing app or site more easily?

Comment: No there is no issue in modified code because i'm hosting it on CDNJS. I want the entire boostrap framework to be non responsive but keep the grid format.

Comment: Have you seen the [Non-responsive Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) example? It follows the [Disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) section, and has a grid in it.

Comment: Yeah ive seen that and tried it but it didnt work for me how would i go about implementing it with the hosted version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure wether this solves the problem, but you could try to set the viewport for mobile devices to the same size as a desktop screen.

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=1024, initial-scale=0.2, minimum-scale=0.2" />
```

Really not sure,... let me know if it's a crap idea then I will remove it.

`*-scale` values are like zoom. When you zoom out you can have more content (pixels) per inch/cm.

Comment: Hi DanFromGerman thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to work.