# Bootstrap 3 Responsiveness/Min-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I did some searching on S/O on how to define a minimum width for a responsive layout in Bootstrap3, but found conflicting answers due to "media queries."

What I want to achieve is my layout being responsive only down to a certain point.  When my layout reaches, say 800px width, I want it to stop being responsive.  Any suggestions on how to do this properly?  Thank you!

**Update:** in order to achieve this, what parameters should be modified at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/  ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

1. scroll to --> Media queries breakpoints

   Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.
2. Now scroll to --> Container sizes

   Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking when you say 'responsive down to 800px' you're saying you want to have a fluid grid down to 800px, then have the layout be a fixed width of 800px.

It's not the easiest of tasks, but generally speaking my suggestion to achieve this would be to override the base bootstrap css (or LESS) using a media query that targets browser widths of 800px or smaller. Something like.

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
 .col-lg-3 {
  width: 100px;
 }
 .col-lg-2 {
  width: 80px;
 }
}
```

What's inside the media query's curly braces above is just an example, but you'd want to target the classes you are using to build your layout. Usually they start with `.col-`. There is a S/O thread that provides more detail here: [How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)