# Positioning my image slider on the screen without it auto-adjusting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so i just finished putting in my image slider. I looked at a few popular websites for examples of how they where able to position theirs. I really liked ebay's. Unfortunately my image slider is positioned in the center of the screen, and adjust as the page gets smaller. I would like to make my image slider the exact same as ebay's in terms of the way that the image slider is positioned slightly to the left, and as you make the page smaller it stays the same in height and width. Then when it hits the left side of the web browser it stops and becomes static. I will add a link to my website so far and i would like to know if you could give me some direction on how to do this.

My site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/
Ebay: http://www.ebay.com/

Comment: you could make "bx-viewport" have a static width. that prevents the resizing of the slider.

Comment: How exactly do i do this with my code? Is their any way you could give me an example? Sorry i am new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the Bootstrap responsiveness by following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) and the slider will not become smaller.

Or you can just replace this `<div class="container">` for this `<div class="" style="width: 1130px; margin: 0px auto;">` on your page.

Comment: One quick thing though. How do i move the whole slider frame over a bit to the left with the same positioning effect it has right now?