# how to disable responsiveness on bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a project for my school where i have to make it responsive, due to some restrictions on bootstrap where it screwed up the viewport with older versions of IE.

Now i have to turn the website non-responsive, instead of slowly deleting all `col-sm/col-xs` classes or re-code the whole website, is there anyway i can disable the responsiveness? Thanks

Example:

```
<div class="container content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 gap">
                <a href="./page_a3da.html" rel="external"><img src="page_home/A3DA_Tab.jpg" alt="banner_a3da"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 gap">
                <a href="./page_fi.html" rel="external"><img src="page_home/FI_Tab.jpg" alt="banner_fi"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 gap">
                <a href="./page_it.html" rel="external"><img src="page_home/IT_Tab.jpg" alt="banner_it"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 gap">
                <a href="./page_mma.html" rel="external"><img src="page_home/MMA_Tab.jpg" alt="banner_mma"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 3 > then its not supporting IE7 and below. but you could read following articles to see if it helps to fix the issue

[making-twitter-bootstrap-3-compatible-with-internet-explorer-7-and-below](http://www.extremecss.com/making-twitter-bootstrap-3-compatible-with-internet-explorer-7-and-below/)

[bootstrap-3-is-awesome-but-older-internet-explorer-is-not](http://launch.ly/blog/bootstrap-3-is-awesome-but-older-internet-explorer-is-not)

And there are some SO questions on exactly what u are asking

[how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

HTH

Comment: thanks mate! i will take a look as the management complains of the website becoming mobile view while viewing it on their macs