# Get height of page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the height of the body of a webpage. I want it to be the value of when the page is loaded on an HD screen at 100% zoom.

The point of this is to then change the viewport in the Meta data and be able to force a mobile browser to load whole page at once, and block the responsiveness of the design.

```
function calculateHeightOfBody() {
var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', /*'width='+width+',*/ 'height='+height);

alert('height is ' + height);
```

I have this function it works but gives me 2 different values on my whether i open the page on a computer or on a phone.

On a computer with and HD screen i get 944 and on a phone i get 2044. 944 is the right value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a high pixel density phone that renders the web page at an increased pixel ratio. Divide height by `window.devicePixelRatio` to account for this.

Note: I don't think your method of getting the height is particularly ideal. Instead of just picking the biggest of like 5 values, you should just use one value. Perhaps `window.innerHeight` would do the trick?

Comment: with window.devicePixelRatio i sitll get 2 different values (1024 on my phone and 955 on a computer), i'll try know with window.innerheight

Comment: Actually, window.innerHeight is the height of the visible space of your screen, so that might not be what you want; mea culpa. Are you sure that the height difference is a mistake though? It's quite possible (probable even) that your body would be different heights on different devices because of text wrapping differently and so forth.

Comment: and same with the innerHeight i get the same 2 values. Well that is the point i dont want the heights to be different, i want them to be exacly the same and then allow the user to zoom in or out on the page without resizing all the content inside of it. I am using Chrom on the computer and on the mobile, I'm not sure if it actually matters.

Comment: But the height might be different through no fault of your height detection code. You might have a paragraph of text that wraps to 2 lines on your wide desktop screen, but gets crammed into 3 lines on your mobile device. That would unavoidably affect the total height of the body.

Comment: i understand that and that is what i want to avoid, i want it to be exaclty the same on a desktop then on a mobile.

Comment: This seems like a different question than your original problem of just accurately detecting the height; perhaps opening a new question would be a good idea?

Comment: i did and the answer was to play with the viewport: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960409/converting-responsive-bootstrap-design-to-static?noredirect=1#comment51829730_31960409

Comment: however i need to detect what value i want to input in the viewport and this value needs to be calculated on the fly for each page of my application, that is why i need a script that calculates the height of the body