# bootstrab nav tab li items in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have those nav-tab items with bootstrap

```
| tab1  |  tab2  |  tab3  |
```

but when my website becomes responsive they to like this

```
| tab 1 | tab2 |
| tab 3 |
```

I have the following code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 no-sid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Recent Events</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Drink Time</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Food Time</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way to always keep them in the same line and even if they become small there is no problem at all.

Comment: You need to convert the tab to bootstrap collapse in mobile view...

Comment: @vignesh could you give me an example?

Comment: Refer the Demo link to have an idea to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3