# How make non responsive in yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I searched about how can I make **non-responsive** project in **yii2**, but I couldn't do it.

[This page](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) says that I have to remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` But I don't know where the **tag** is.

Could you please help me to make my website **non-responsive** easily?

Comment: check views/layouts/main

Comment: @csminb I know that, I've written tags in `tags.php` and included to `frontend/views/layouts/main.php` but there is no `viewport` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Yii2 id twitter-boostrap-3 based this mean how is possible make bootstrap not responsive  .. these link could be useful

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/11/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site/

[How to remove responsive features in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

essentially

1 : Remove the viewport

2: Remove the max-width on the .container class

```
.container{
  max-width: none !important;
  width:970px;
}
```

3: Fixing the navbars

4: Using the grid col-xs-* classes in addition to or in place of the medium/large ones

Answer (score 1):

The `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is in your layouts. You have diffrent one for `backend` and `frontend` if you use `yii2-advanced-app`

by default it is:

`backend - app/backend/views/layouts/main.php`

`frontend - app/frontend/views/layouts/main.php`