# Stop Bootstrap under a minimum width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a nasty project in my hand with a lot of bootstrap in it. The thing is, I need to make lock at a certain 1024px and I can't think of how. I'm locking the body at 1024px but bootstrap still changes the layout regarding the width and I can't simply remove all the column classes to use only 1 since it would not adapt itself any more.

What ideas could I use to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've added the minimum width value in css and started by declaring that the LG classes were the xs and removing the others. But that started to break everything.

Comment: Post a minimal example of code that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own customized Bootstrap css ([create one here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints))
 instead of the original/regular one. In the 'Media queries breakpoints' section, just change `@screen-xs`, `@screen-sm`, and `@screen-md` to `1024px` and then download the customized version.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is designed to be mobile first and scale up rather than down.

You could reverse this by having a lot of fixed values in your own css file that overrides the bootstrap media queries below 1024. Essentially this would be a lot of work because you would be reversing bootstrap's mobile first design.

Comment: So I need to reverse everything?

Answer (score 1):

This has been [already asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935601/how-to-remove-responsive-features-in-twitter-bootstrap-3), and the steps to make Bootstrap 3 non-responsive are [described in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#disable-responsive). In your case, it sounds like simply using the `col-xs-*` classes will work as these columns don't stack vertically and "change the layout". From the docs:

> For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place
>   of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid
>   scales to all resolutions.

https://www.codeply.com/go/g1dEHU6EOX